# how to take int value from a class and use it in another one

Tags: java, android, class, gridview

I need to get the position of the grid view in the onItemClick

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Position = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Position = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Position = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Position = 3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Position = 4;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

and use it in a different Fragment class in a switch loop

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_city, container, false);

    int position = new MainActivity().Position;

    ArrayList<CityScreenItem> city = new ArrayList<>();

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            city.add(new CityScreenItem("Giza", "Giza is good",
                    R.drawable.dubai));
            break;
        case 1:
            city.add(new CityScreenItem("Dubai", "Dubai is good",
                    R.drawable.egypt));
            break;
    }


    CityScreenAdapter adapter = new CityScreenAdapter(getActivity(), city);
    ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

but it always displays the first case when I check this was due to the `int position = new MainActivity().Position;`code but I could not find the answer.
**Note**
I did make a public int for Position at the beginning of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new object every time:

```
int position = new MainActivity().Position;
```

This will reset the position to what you are setting it to.  Make Position static.

```
public static int POSITION = 0;
```

This should fix your problem.  Access it like below:

```
int position = MainActivity.POSITION;
```